# DataGrid with several columns is not known

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I need to write a DataGrid with several columns is not known.
 Other words   the first row 10 columns,the second 7 columns, on the third 15th. 
How can I build the DataGrid in such a way?
In each cell should be a string, (this comes from several queries, so I can not do Binding)

c# and WPF

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just `join` or `union` your different queries into one DataTable and then bind it to your DataGrid.